# Advanced Routing Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I currently have a simple `CRUD` application built in `Laravel` interacting with a `database` of `Books`. This is my `routes.php` file:

```
Route::model('book', 'Book');

//Show pages
Route::get('/', 'BookController@index');
Route::get('book/create', 'BookController@create');
Route::get('book/edit/{book}', 'BookController@edit');
Route::get('book/delete/{book}', 'BookController@delete');
Route::get('book/view/{book}', 'BookController@view');

//Handle form submissions
Route::post('create', 'BookController@handleCreate');
Route::post('edit', 'BookController@handleEdit');
Route::post('delete', 'BookController@handleDelete');
```

Then in my `views` folder I've the following files:

```
create.blade.php
edit.blade.php
index.blade.php
layout.blade.php
view.blade.php
```

The `Controller` is `BookController`:

```
class BookController extends BaseController {

    //View page - Shows list of books
    public function index(){
        $books = Book::all();
        //compact()creates array of the books using names as keys
        return View::make('index', compact('books'));
    }

    //Create page - Shows create Form
    public function create(){
        return View::make('create');
    }

    //Logic to add a new book to the DB
    public function handleCreate(){
        $book = new Book;
        $book->book_name = Input::get('name');
        $book->book_desc = Input::get('desc');
        $book->save();
        return Redirect::action('BookController@index');
    }

    //Edit page - Shows edit form and populates with book info
    public function edit(Book $book){
        return View::make('edit', compact('book'));
    }

    //Logic to update an existing book in the DB
    public function handleEdit(){
        $book = Book::findOrFail(Input::get('id'));
        $book->book_name = Input::get('name');
        $book->book_desc = Input::get('desc');
        $book->save();
        return Redirect::action('BookController@index');
    }

    //Delete page
    public function delete(Book $book){
        //Show delete confirmation page
        return View::make('delete', compact('book'));
    }

    public function handleDelete(){
        //Handle delete logic...
        $id = Input::get('book');
        $book = Book::findOrFail($id);  
        $book->delete();
        return Redirect::action('BookController@index');
    }

    //View 
    public function view(Book $book){
        return View::make('view', compact('book'));
    }
}
```

My question is how can I modify my routes if I were to nest the different `views` in a sub folder called `books`. I tried creating a folder called `books` and pasted the `views` into it and when I ran the application it said it could not find the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## View Subfolders

You can simply use dot syntax to navigate down the folder structure within the views folder. Take your index view for example, if you want that to live in `views\books` you would do:

```
public function index(){
    $books = Book::all();

    return View::make('books.index', compact('books'));
}
```

That's it! Laravel makes it really simple.

So if we want to take this deeper, what about another subfolder inside `books` called `travel` giving you `views\books\travel`:

```
public function index(){
    $books = Book::all();

    return View::make('books.travel.index', compact('books'));
}
```

## Resource Routing

It's also worth noting that Laravel makes routing to a RESTful controller like your `BookController` really easy using `Route::resource`. All the mapping GET and POST requests to your methods is done for you. Check it out here: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers